# Created Custom Audio component in Asset share commons everything is working fine except not able to get thumbnail image in audio files

Tags: aem, thumbnails, assetslibrary

I have created custom Audio Component in Asset share commons in AEM, everything is working fine except I am not able to get the thumbnail in audio file (.mp3 and. wav).I have done some R&D then I found that Audio files does not have any rendition except original one. So my requirement is that is there anyway that we can add thumbnail in audio file.

PFB Screenshot of .mp3 node in crx.

[image]

See in above picture there is no rendition except original one that's why it is coming as without thumbnail, When I copy any image and paste it here (manually) then thumbnail is appear in audio files.

[image]

[image]

But I don't want to do it manually this thing. Can you please suggest some way how can I solve this issue? It will be very helpful for me.

Related Discussions
Customize Rendition - Add new rendition for image Placeholder image
5090

[image]

Comment: I have tried it ,but it is not working in the case of audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `DAM Update Asset` workflow. There is a step, `Process Thumbnails` in which you can add the MIME types for which you would like to generate renditions (or skip them as well).

e.g. http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/admin/console/content/models.html